# Drive isn't recognized

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation

So that few days I've been trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my external hdd (I have two and have tried installing on both of the them). As soon as the installation is done it says I have to restart which I do.

This then boots into Windows because that's what is on my internal ssd and what is set for default. So I restart again and go to the boot options and the external drive doesn't show up.

After the first time I tried installing I now get Ubuntu as a boot option whether a drive is plugged in or not. I've tried booting with that both with an hdd plugged in and without Grub pops up saying something like to the effect of limited commands are available at this time.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. I just want to have a working Ubuntu hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you installed Ubuntu on the external HDD but installed the boot-loader on the internal SSD.  When you boot back into Ubuntu using the live CD and attempt to install, what options are you picking?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the GRUB is installed on the internal SSD and is configured to look for the drive which it isn't recognizing but for whatever reason ins't finding it.  Ironically this is related to a subject I was discussing with another user in just the past few hour.

Installing Ubuntu on EXTERNAL media is fun and practical, a my own bio explains, but for it to work right, it is best that it be the only drive connected when setting it up, otherwise what happens is what you are experiencing.

First, to fix your internal SSD, please download and burn this [boot repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) disk/flash.

Use the boot repair to boot the computer with only the internal SSD connected and us its boot repair utility to automatically fix its grub.

Next, if you want your newly created external drives to be independently bootable, you can use the boot repair disk to fix them, but for each one they need to be the only drive in the system when the boot repair is being made.  After each drive is repaired, you will (probably) be able to boot your computer to the external drives, even with the SSD still attached.